templ error parsing style attribute of HTML element
I am trying to set the style attribute of an HTML li element using templ but I am getting parser errors; specifically parsing error: for: expected nodes, but none were found: line 265, col 16. It works just fine for the class attribute so am I just doing something wrong for style?
I'm trying to set the style dynamically to gridRow: x / span y where x and y are calculated. Since this is just a css property, I think I might be able to generate a class with this css property for each element but that seems like an odd thing to have to do if other attributes are able to be set dynamically...
Example
<ol>
  for _, e := range events {
    <li class={ e.Class } style={ e.Style }> <---- error here
      <a>
        <p>{ e.Title }</p>
      </a>
    </li>
  }
</ol>

PS I was unable to attach a tag for templ but for clarity this is the package I am referencing: https://templ.guide/

After discovering the templ discussion board, I noticed a thread that was also mentioning this issue. And one of the maintainers of the package mentioned that this functionality was intentionally not supported for security reasons.
In order to get this to work I had to construct the html in a func and then pass it to templ using @templ.Raw. This isn't ideal but until you can inline styles this is what I managed to get working...
// view helper

func EventTemplate(event types.Event) string {
    str := "<li class=\"" + GetEventClass(event) + "\" style=\"" + GetEventStyle(event) + "\">\n"
    str += "  <a href=\"#\" class=\"group absolute inset-1 flex flex-col overflow-y-auto rounded-lg bg-blue-50 p-2 text-xs leading-5 hover:bg-blue-100\">\n"
    str += "    <p class=\"order-1 font-semibold text-blue-700\">" + event.Title + "</p>\n"
    str += "    <p class=\"text-blue-500 group-hover:text-blue-700\"><time datetime=\"" + event.StartDate.Format(time.RFC3339) + "\">" + event.StartDate.Format(time.Kitchen) + "</time></p>\n"
    str += "  </a>\n"
    str += "</li>\n"
    return str
}

and then in my .templ file
<ol class="col-start-1 col-end-2 row-start-1 grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-7 sm:pr-8" style="grid-template-rows: 1.75rem repeat(288, minmax(0, 1fr)) auto">
  for _, e := range events {
    @templ.Raw(EventTemplate(e))
  }
</ol>

